# Angular not importing mixin

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble trying to use a mixin.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyxtux?file=angular.json

Here is my stackblitz.

**I'm probably missing something**, but i do not understand why mixin is undefined if is imported in the *src/styles.scss* file, which is added in the *angular.json* build section.

As far as I understand, this src/styles.scss file and its contents are loaded at buildtime, thus the mixin should be imported. In fact, if I set a css property for html p tag (background-color) in the same file, I can see the effect it has, but mixin is not defined. Thus the imports, are well done... You can test that by commenting the line 3 of https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyxtux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All components are isolated, encapsulated pieces of logic in Angular. So the component's CSS is being compiled by itself - the other files aren't there. There is no reason for them to be there!

Just like you import anything to use in Typescript you also need to import anything you use in SCSS.

You can import files that contain variables and mixins or functions as many times as you want as they do not affect the bundle size.

So we have to import SCSS files that we want to use for each component.

If we wanna use global CSS then import SCSS files into styles.scss that can produces CSS and apply that CSS selectors into components template

Comment: So you mean that I have to add the import to the global scss file in each component scss file?

Comment: in your case you have to import multidirectional mixin into app.component's scss file then use it in that component

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another way? I wouldn't like to have to import that file in all of my components scss files.

Comment: you have to import it just whereever you want to use not to all components

Comment: In case I want to use it in all of my components?

Comment: I ran into this too - if I import a mixin file into the styles.scss (global) - the build fails and says the mixin is missing.  If I import the mixin directly into the component's scss file = works.  That is so dumb - is there really no way around it?  If I can use variables outside the component in the styles.scss file - I should be able to use a mixin too, but it keeps failing.