# Why is my custom Angular SCSS import failing?

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

I am thinking this is a Webpack or angular.json thing possibly.

I created a _mixins.scss file under the theme folder. Also, in the folder I imported the mixin file in the custom.scss file.  Then in the main styles.scss the custom.scss gets imported.  Then inside of an angular component I use the @include to pull in the mixin, but get an error. I also have in the angular.json file the styles file marked there.

I've also tried switching to @use and @importing the mixin directly into the styles.scss = no dice.

Similar stackoverflow question with link to example: [Angular not importing mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694893/angular-not-importing-mixin)

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
7 │     @include card-hover-effect();
```

Now if I import the mixin directly into the component's scss file and import the _variables.scss in the mixin file - it all works, but not ideal.

I get that components are encapsulated, but you can access global styles and variables... why not mixins? So, how do you get global mixins and access them like the variables in a component - without importing them directly into the component's scss file?

[image: folders]

[image: custom.scss]

[image: Component Scss]

[image: angular.json file]

Mixin code:

```
@mixin card-hover-effect() {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.02);
    box-shadow: $card-box-shadow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you importing custom?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 custom is imported into the main styles.scss file.  The global one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be right that it's an '`angular.json`-thing', because I see no issue in the code.

It could be that you need to add the path of your folder containing the mixins to you `angular.json`'s `stylePreprocessorOptions`.

It would look something like this:

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options": {
      // ...
      "styles": [
        "src/styles.scss"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "src/theme"
        ]
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: no dice - same error with above.  The odd part is that I can use variables out of the _variables.scss file, but for some reason mixins.scss (even if I add it to the variables file as a test) will not work.  Which has to be some compile/build time thing to me.  What needs to be adjusted is still a mystery lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the advice from @H3AR7B3A7 and add the path to your mixins in the `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths` in your `angular.json`, then the correct way to import any scss file starting with `_` in that folder is simply:

`@import 'mixins';`

You don't need the `./` part in front.

Also, although `@use` is currently the preferred method of importing variables, mixins, etc. from other sass files, it will not work without modifications to your code. You can read about the differences here:

https://kentwynn.com/frontend-languages/use-vs-import-in-sass-which-one-should-you-choose/kentwynn/27/03/2023/